# CameraUpdateFactory zoom to does not zoom map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a method that zooms the map to the user's specified zoom level but it will not zoom using `CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(9f);`

However It will zoom correctly if I do this

```
CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(location).zoom(9).build();

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
```

but this requires that I have a location to zoom to.

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views) it looks like I just access the `zoomTo` method statically but when I do that nothing happens.

Am I using the first method incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo` does not directly alter the map, instead it returns a `CameraUpdate` value . This value will have the new zoom level set by you and the other parameters like target, bearing, etc will be retained as they are. Now for the value to take effect, you need to apply the `CameraUpdate` to the map using `animateCamera(CameraUpdate) or moveCamera(CameraUpdate)`

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Saved me. I wanted to indiscriminately zoom and your suggestion makes this possible. :)